# Check area contains point in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to check if a place is inside the area on maps.google.com
Sample example.
I have some area in maps.google.com in my
[website](http://s6.ifotos.pl/img/CapturePN_xnqhqen.PNG)

Now I want to have one input where I can write some city, now it will be New York,
So if New York is outside my area i need return 0 and if it inside area i need return 1.

Did you hear something about script working like it?
Please help me-

Answer (score 3):

You can use the containsLocation method of the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) or [Openlayers](http://www.openlayers.org/)! Both have a function for checking if a coordinate is within a polygon.

Google Maps API: [API documentation of containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

OpenLayers: [Intersection Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/intersects.html)

Comment: i will try it but i'm beginer so i can have some problems:) than You for fast response!

Comment: LatLngBounds will always be a rectangle.  What is probably required is point in polygon.  What format is the polygon in (can't tell from your picture), is it KML or a native Google Maps API v3 Polygon?

Comment: just line in maps.google.com

Comment: There is a "containsLocation" method in the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

Comment: Actually, when you say "just a line in maps.google.com", how did you create it?  Is it in "My Maps"/"My Places" (in which case you can access it as KML) or did you create it using the Google Maps API v3 (you don't have that tag on your question).

Comment: @geocodezip: You're right, it's a rectangle! The suggested method should do the job.

Comment: maps.google.com - my place - place - edit - and i can edit sharpe

Comment: You will need to use the Google Maps API v3 to do the point in polygon analysis.  Your shape can be accessed as KML, you will probably need to use a proxy and a third party parser to do what you want.  [example using geoxml](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html) - [example using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html).